# React Native In-App Purchase returns empty array product list on Android

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement an in-app purchase with "react-native-iap": "^4.6.2" library. On iOS everything works fine but with android, I am trying to get a product list but it returns an empty array.

Steps:

1. Downloaded "react-native-iap": "^4.6.2"
   2.Put permissions  in to AndroidManifest.xml
2. Create a signed aab and upload it to the play console as an open-close test.
3. wait a couple of days.
4. Try to get a product list, connection is true but returns the product list as an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified SkuProductID inside
something like this...

**`getProducts(['sku_1','sku_2']);`**